# Spring MVC and bootstrap modal form : how to create server-side validation for it?

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, jquery-validate

I'm newbie at spring and front-end at all.
I have (not mine) an old front-end code to  show modal form over some page :

modal form is:

```
    <div id="myModalForm" class="modal inmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog ">
            <div class="modal-content animated fadeIn">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="modal"><span
                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only"></span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><spring:message code="entity.modal.title"/></h4>
                </div>
                <div id="modalContent" class="modal-body">
                    <form id="createForm" name="createForm" class="" action="/entity/create"
                          method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                          ...
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

form is shown from java scripts. Button that invokes form is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tbl').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            dom: 'l<"toolbar">frtip',
            initComplete: function () {
                $("div.toolbar")
                    .html('<button id="new_entity_btn" type="button" class = "btn btn-white" onclick="openCreateWindow()" ><spring:message
        code="entity.table.create.btn"/> </button>');
            }
        });
        /*activate tooltips*/
        $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        });

    });
</script>
```

and onclick for button is:

```
<script>
    function openCreateWindow() {
        $('#myModalForm').modal('show');
    }

</script>
```

Now as you can see `#myModalForm` is not a Spring view form as it doesn't generate even get-request to be shown. It just appears over existing page in modal mode. Now the question is how to create **server-side** validation for it? I've tried next:

1) refactor it to spring mvc form i.e. via

```
<form:form ... />
```

tag with attribute 
`ModelAttribute='MyFormAttribute'`. But i have no idea how to create back-end object for MyFormAttribute as appearance of form doesn't generate get-request. And idea was to have on post method of controller something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/entity/create"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
String createNewEntity(
@ModelAttribute("MyFormAttribute") MyEntity entity,
BindingResult bindingResult,
Model model)
```

2) Trying to change post method of controller so that it might return error. But there is no way to create bindingResult parameter in case if form is not mvc one

3) Trying to validate via jQuery.validate i.e. smth. like :

```
<script>
    /*form validation*/
    $().ready(function () {
        $("#createForm").validate({
            rules: {
                Field1: {
                    remote: function () {
                        var r = {
                            url: '/validateEntityField1',
                            type: "POST"
                        };
                        return r;
                    }
                },
                Field2: {
                    remote: function () {
                        var r = {
                            url: '/validateEntityField2',
                            type: "POST"
                        };
                        return r;
                    }
                }
...
            },
            errorElement: "em",
            highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).fadeOut(function () {
                    $(element).fadeIn();
                });
                $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass)
            },
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass)
            }
        })
        ;
    });
</script>
```

But it looks rather ugly as i should validate every field separately on its own end point and. Besides form has file input so i should send it twice or smth.

So, how could i achieve next issue:

1. leave modal form over existing page
2. validate it on server side. It would be nice to make validation against whole entity.

Comment: take a look at this - https://gist.github.com/Coder-ACJHP/a5008cac0bb21092d6b153cd7b9fe26f

Answer (score 0):

Answering on my commented question. Not the exact code you are looking but will give you an idea. Though it depends on individual choice, in controller you can use ValidationUtils as shown below. Here you can map your error messages and json response which later on you want on your front-end:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody JsonResponse addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, Errors errors, Model model) {
    JsonResponse response = new JsonResponse();

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(result, "firstname", "Firstname is required. It can not be empty.");
    if (user.getFirstname().length() < 4 || user.getFirstname().length() > 32) {
        errors.rejectValue("firstname", "Firstname must be between 4 and 32 characters.");
    }

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(result, "lastname", "Lastname is required. It can not be empty.");
    if (user.getLastname().length() < 4 || user.getLastname().length() > 32) {
        errors.rejectValue("lastname", "Lastname must be between 4 and 32 characters.");
    }
    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        userList.add(user);
        response.setStatus("SUCCESS");
        response.setResult(userList);
    } else {
        response.setStatus("FAIL");
        response.setResult(result.getAllErrors());
    }

    return response;
}
```

And I picked the sample for Bootstrap Modal from here:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp

Somewhere in your html:

```
<!-- Modal body -->
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-form-label" for="username">Enter your First Name</label> 
<i class="fas fa-users"></i> 
<input type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control">
</div>
....
....
</div>
```

Put up (similar to this) in your ajax:

```
if (response.status == "SUCCESS") {
            userInfo = "<ol>";
            for (i = 0; i < response.result.length; i++) {
                userInfo += "<br><li><b>Firstname</b> : "
                        + response.result[i].firstname
                        + response.result[i].lastname;
            }
```

And

```
errorInfo = "";
            for (i = 0; i < response.result.length; i++) {
                errorInfo += "<br>" + (i + 1) + ". "
                        + response.result[i].code;
            }
            $('#error').html(
                    "<b>Errors found during validation : </b>"
                            + errorInfo);
```

I created a small piece of code for this. You can take a look here on [GitHub](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootStrapModalShowCase2).